# Does embedded Kafka downloads Kafka at run time

Tags: java, scala, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-boot-test

Does EmbeddedKafka library downloads Kafka at runtime and deletes once the tests are completed if not how does embedded Kafka works internally.

Comment: Unlikely but an interesting question - best to look at the source code and see. I suspect it's simple in memory Java that honours the requirements of producers and consumers.